# Is there a daily dairy of WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, international-relations

Can someone suggest a hardcover book that comprehensively chronicles the history of WW II on a day-by-day or week-by-week diary basis that spans 1939 - 1945? *Comprehensively* in terms of addressing the various nations involved, weapons used, technologies developed, the concentration camps, military strategies and tactics, battle outcomes, civilian casualties, politics, etc.

I've searched for such a book but can only find diaries narrowly written from one person's perspective.

I realize that because this war was so enormous that a single volume book will only be able to summarize it, thereby glossing over many details; that's to be expected. So if there happens to be a *multi-volume* treatment of this subject I'd be interested in that too.

Comment: We generally consider book recommendations to be off-topic here because what makes a "good" book is highly subjective. I suspect that, if such a thing exists, your requirements will only be met by a multi-volume work.

Comment: Why the book has to be "hard cover"? How can this be relevant?

Comment: @Alex Hardcover is relevant by way of durability. You know, sturdy vs flimsy ?

Comment: @Steve Bird So sorry, didn't know this is off topic. If "good" books are off topic what about "not-so-good" ones ?

Comment: @Steve: it depends on the quality of the product. I have many soft cover books (by Dover publisher) which are very old, had a lot of usage, and do not fall apart. And I also have hard cover books which fell apart after  some moderate usage.

Comment: A quick Google search for ["WW2 Day by Day"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=world+war+ii+day+by+day&ie=UTF-8&oe=) turns up several (athough you might need to source them second-hand). Whether they are comprehensive enough for your needs; only you can judge.

Comment: @Steve  "Good" and "Not Good" are both subjective; we do our best work with question that have [authoritative answers](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/1401) - answers that can be verified, answers that are subject to agreement & consensus, not argument and debate.

Comment: @Killing Time Thank you for your input. I missed "WW2 Day by Day" in my search. It looks comprehensive, apparently is available new and is in hardcover format. Your comment was very useful. Thanks again.

Comment: Diaries are _by definition_ written from a single perspective.

Comment: There's a twitter feed I used to follow called [Real Time WWII](https://twitter.com/RealTimeWWII). You could get the same effect you are looking for by going back through their feed.

Comment: If you know German then check this : https://archive.org/details/kriegstagebuchde01jacorich/page/n1/mode/2up  . This is Kriegstagebuch des Oberkommandos der Wehrmacht . There is also shortened extract in Serbian (mostly considers events in Balkans, but also mentions major "world" events) http://forum.burek.com/srbi-u-ratnom-dnevniku-vermahta-t42611.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of Victor Klemperer? Probably the most famous diary in the history of the world.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Klemperer

Comment: I had not heard of Victor Klemperer, thank you for sharing. I might be wrong, but it appears that he wrote a "narrow" (non-comprehensive) diary from his personal perspective only; similar to Viktor Frankl's Man's Search For Meaning; which is a great book on many levels but not what I'm looking for right now. I could see reading Klemperer's book perhaps further into the future.